# how do I predict answers in tensorflow using a model trained with linear regression?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've modified some really simple tutorial code (below) to train a linear regression model (way simple because I'm trying to learn how it works). The training works fine as I get the predicted result. I am, however, finding it impossible to figure out the syntax to feed in a piece of test data (x) and get the model to spit out the predicted y value. The error I get is "cannot feed value of shape (1,) for Tensor which has shape  (?,1).

Can somebody take a look at the last section (#rebuild the graph so we can make a prediction from test data....) and point me in the right direction please? Thank you in advance.

sample data for x is in column 0 of each row in the CSV

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import csv

//# Model linear regression y = Wx + b  
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1], name='varx')  
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1,1]), name='W')  
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]),name='b')  
product = tf.matmul(x,W)  
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,1],name='vary')  
y = product + b  
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1], name='varouty')  

//# Cost function sum((y_-y)**2)  
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y_-y))

//# Training using Gradient Descent to minimize cost  
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.0000001).minimize(cost)  

sess = tf.Session()  
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()  
sess.run(init)  
epochs = 500  

list1 = []  
with open(r'c:\temp\book1.csv','r') as f:  
    reader = csv.reader(f)  
    for row in reader:  
        i2 = int(row[0])  
        list1.append(i2)  


//#now loop through the list and add the items  
for i in range(epochs):  
  //# Create fake data for y = W.x + b where W = 2, b = 0
    i0 = list1[i]  
    xs = np.array([[i0]])   
    ys = np.array([[2*i0]])  
  //# Train  
    feed = { x: xs, y_: ys }  
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict=feed)  
    print("xs=" + str(xs))  
    print("ys=" + str(ys))  
    print("After %d iterations:" % i)  
    print("W: %f" % sess.run(W))  
    print("b: %f" % sess.run(b))  



//# NOTE: W should be close to 2, and b should be close to 0

//#rebuild the graph so we can make a prediction from test data....
xg = tf.get_default_graph()  

x_input = xg.get_tensor_by_name('varx:0')  
y_output = xg.get_tensor_by_name('vary:0')  
W1 = xg.get_tensor_by_name('W:0')  
b1 = xg.get_tensor_by_name('b:0')  

with tf.Session(graph=xg) as sess1:  
    x_example = [3]  
    y_prediction = sess1.run(y_output,feed_dict={x_input:x_example})  
    print(y_prediction)
```

Comment: By the error message, it requires you to feed data with shape (?, 1), that means it can accept ? (any) number of examples with a length of one. In your example `x_example = [3]` has shape `(1, )` which doesn't fulfill the requirement. Can you try to predict `x_example = [[3]]` (which has shape `(1, 1)` that fulfills the requirement) and see if it works?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It's now giving a different error related to the line y_prediction = ....   : the new error is InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'vary' with dtype float and shape [?,1]

Comment: I'm wondering if my understanding is flawed? I'm expecting it to work like math where I would give it an x and it would spit out a y after it's trained. But the new error message seems to suggest I need both a new x and a new y. I don't understand how this makes sense, or maybe I'm reading it wrong.

Comment: Your understanding is correct, that's exactly what it should do `y = wx + b`. And it works when I don't rebuild the graph and just call `y_prediction = sess.run(y ,feed_dict={x:[[3]]})` after training is done. Seems like rebuilding the graph requires re-training, will add an answer if I can figure out a working way. A bit rusty on tensorflow.